# Why does Postgres function complain about mismatch errors with language clause?

Tags: postgresql, function

I am trying to write a function to auto database cleanups, but I keep getting an error "ERROR:  mismatched parentheses at end of input LINE 26: $func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;".

but, when I remove the language string from the line tha"ERROR:  no language specified
SQL state: 42P13" How does one specify a language without causing a mismatch error in version 11?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION for_loop_through_query( limit_days INTEGER DEFAULT 14 )
RETURNS VOID AS $func$
DECLARE
    job_rec RECORD;
    limit TEXT := limit_days || ' days';
BEGIN
    FOR job_rec IN (SELECT id public.ci_builds WHERE finished_at < now() - limit::interval AND status NOT IN ('running', 'pending')
    LOOP
         RAISE NOTICE 'Processing JOB ID : % ...', job_rec.id

       --Drop job IDs
       DELETE FROM public.ci_builds WHERE id = job_rec.id
       DELETE FROM public.ci_builds_metadata WHERE (id = job_rec.id OR build_id = job_rec.id)
       DELETE FROM public.ci_job_artifacts WHERE JOB_ID = job_rec.id
       DELETE FROM public.ci_job_variables WEHRE JOB_ID = job_rec.id

    END LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'RE-INDEXING TABLES...'

    --Re-index the tables
    REINDEX TABLE public.ci_builds
    REINDEX TABLE public.ci_builds_metadata
    REINDEX TABLE public.ci_job_artifacts
    REINDEX TABLE public.ci_job_variables
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Because you failed to terminate the statement  "  RAISE NOTICE 'Processing JOB ID : % ...', job_rec.id"  and every statement after it.  You need a semi-colon (;) at the end of each statement.

Comment: I had the terminators all up in there, but pgadmin was complaining so I removed them, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create in PG 11 a function using following clauses:

```
select version();
                                                 version                        

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (R
ed Hat 4.8.5-39), 64-bit
(1 row)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(limit_days INTEGER DEFAULT 14) RETURNS VOID 
AS $func$
DECLARE
 v numeric;
BEGIN
 RAISE NOTICE 'test';
 v = 1;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

You are missing a `;` after `RAISE NOTICE` statements.

Comment: So, when I add the ";" in raise statements, I get and error: ERROR:  mismatched parentheses at or near ";"
LINE 9:     RAISE NOTICE 'Processing JOB ID : % ...', job_rec.id;

Comment: As already said you need to add a `;` *after each statement*. Not sure why pgadmin does not check this (I would suggest use psql instead).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I re-build using your framework and it works fine...